# Crear un programa que determine si un string introducido por un usuario empieza con un número o con una letra

Tags: javascript

```
    function tiene_numeros(texto) {
        var numeros = prompt("Intoduce numeros")
        var texto = "asddfffdsss";
        for (i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {

            if (numeros.indexOf(texto.charAt(i), 0) != -1) {
                console.log("Empieza con numeros" + numeros);
            }
            else{
                console.log("empieza con letras" + numeros);
            }
        }
        return  numeros;
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Las preguntas pidiendo ayuda con ejercicios o tarea escolar deben incluir el enunciado del problema, un resumen del trabajo realizado hasta el momento (incluyendo código) y una descripción de los errores o dificultades que se estén encontrando. Lee [ask] y visita el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar RegEx para evaluar:

```
var texto = "_asddfffdsss";
if (texto.match(/^\d/)) {
   console.log('numero');
}
else if ((texto.match(/^\D/)) && (!texto.match(/^\W/))) {
   console.log('texto');
}
else
{
    console.log('otra cosa')
}
```

Comment: No todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas. Para más detalles lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rubén 